# What does -n refer for this line of code?

Tags: python, pandas

```
%%timeit -n 10
```

I've understood that:
10 : operation for 10 loops.
%%timeit : cellular magic function to calculate time of execution.

When I tried to change it using something (e.g. -f), then the output is:

> UsageError: option -f not recognized ( allowed: "n:r:tcp:qo" )

Means, we can use n,r,tcp or qo instead of `n`.

So, I want to know about the reason to use -n or about the other usable alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

as especified in the doc [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#command-line-interface)  the `n` parameter refers to :

> how many times to execute ‘statement’

another parameters are:

[image]

> When I tried to change it using something (e.g. -f), then the output is:

as you can see, there is no paramter `f`